# gRPC python client authentication example

Tags: python, ssl, grpc, grpc-python

How do you use the gRPC python auth library for both client and server authentication? The [docs](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html#base-case---no-encryption-or-authentication-4) only cover server authentication.

Are there additional flags in `grpc.secure_channel()` that need to be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The server side, needs to have:

```
server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials(
    ((private_key, cert_chain),), root_cert, require_client_auth=True)
server.add_secure_port('%s:%d' % (ip, port), server_credentials)
```

`root_cert` is the root CA to verify the client certificate. `private_key` and `cert_chain` will be the certificate the server uses to be verified by the client.

And the client side:

```
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(
        certificate_chain=cert_chain, private_key=cert_key, root_certificates=root_ca)
channel = grpc.secure_channel('%s:%d' % (hostname, port), creds)
```

Where `root_ca` is the root CA to verify the server's certificate chain, and `cert_chain` and `cert_key` are used to authenticate the client.